# Angularjs $timeout not executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, timeout, settimeout

I'm new to Angularjs and want to add a timer once the page load.  I read a number of similar kind of questions here but still I couldn't resolve my issue. I added `data-ng-init="init()"` to my view. 
This is the controller:

```
    'use strict';

    angular.module('tempApp')
      .controller('MainController',['$scope','$timeout','dService', function ($scope,$timeout, dService) {

        $scope.init =  function(){
            console.log("Safety checkStatus page load");
            $timeout(callAtTimeout(),3000);
        }


    function callAtTimeout(){
        console.log("Safety checkStatus ***");
    }

 }]);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Zusee/s6xy48t0/9/

Here dService is separate service js file I'm going to use. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tempApp">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
<script type="text/javascript">
       'use strict';

           angular.module('tempApp', [])
             .controller('MainController',['$scope','$timeout', function ($scope,$timeout) {

               $scope.init =  function(){
                   console.log("Safety checkStatus page load");

                   $timeout(callAtTimeout, 3000);
               };
               function callAtTimeout(){
                       console.log("Safety checkStatus ***");
                   }

$scope.init();
        }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this?

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('tempApp')
      .controller('MainController',['$scope','$timeout','dService', function ($scope,$timeout, dService) {

       $scope.init =  function(){

            console.log("Safety checkStatus page load");

            $timeout(function () {
                  $scope.callAtTimeout();
            }, 1000);

       } 


       $scope.callAtTimeout = function(){
           console.log("Safety checkStatus ***");
       }

       $scope.init();
 }]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. But still it's not working as expect.

Comment: Sorry . one question ... why you use }]); two times ?

Comment: mm..sorry It's typo. :

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  But why does it work?  Initially I had

$timeout($scope.callAtTimeout(), 1000);

then I changed it to 

$timeout(function () { $scope.callAtTimeout() }, 1000); 

and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 'use strict';

        angular.module('tempApp')
          .controller('MainController',['$scope','$timeout','dService', function ($scope,$timeout, dService) {

            $scope.init =  function(){
                console.log("Safety checkStatus page load");
                $timeout(function () {
                  callAtTimeout()
                }, 3000);
            }  }]);


        function callAtTimeout(){
            console.log("Safety checkStatus ***");
        }

     }]);
```

You may also need to call $scope.init() explicitly

Comment: Thanks for your support. I tried that too with no luck.

Comment: Please check my edited answer for changed $timeout()

Comment: @urvashi ` I added data-ng-init="init()"`  You dont need to call it explicitely

Comment: Yes thats also correct,since html code is not here so i added 'may' :)

Comment: @Zusee in that case please add a fiddle as it is working for me,need more details of ur code.

Comment: @Zusee,did u called $scope.init() ?

Comment: Yes I did try but I think it isn't necessary I called during page the page load.

Comment: Waiting for ur fiddle :)

Comment: @ZuseeWeekin: check here https://jsfiddle.net/s6xy48t0/10/ . I updated your fiddle. Now the alerts are showing. You were getting an error as the service wasn't defined in the fiddle.

Comment: @ZuseeWeekin have solved ur problem i think pls check ur fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Add 'dService'

```
.controller('MainController',['$scope','$timeout', 'dService', function ($scope,$timeout, dService) {
```

And use like

```
$timeout(callAtTimeout,3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is extra parenthesis in $scope.init()

```
$scope.init =  function(){
     console.log("Safety checkStatus page load");
     $timeout(function () {
          callAtTimeout();
     }, 3000);
};
```

Comment: I have data-ng-init="init()" in my view.

Comment: then no need to call in controller, but remove extra parenthesis @ZuseeWeekin

Comment: mm..sorry It's typo. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you need [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout) if you want to set timer.

`$timeout` will execute once.

Try with [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

Here is the changes :

```
$scope.init = function() {
          console.log("Safety checkStatus page load");
          $interval($scope.callAtTimeout, 1000);
        }
        $scope.callAtTimeout = function() {

          console.log("Safety checkStatus ***");
        }
```

Here is the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6TtZk73X8lKmq4VbdIQQ?p=preview)